# Can you use an array index value as a parametre in a predicate to filter an array

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, nspredicate

I'm wondering if it's possible to filter an NSArray with a NSPredicate using an array index value, ie

```
NSArray *completeArray = ...;
NSArray *filteredArray = [completeArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate 
   predicateWithFormat:@"ANY (arrayIndex < 5) && (Other conditions here)"];
```

I'm using core data, and cannot use a primary key or other identifiers for the objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `subarrayWithRange:` then filter the subarray

```
NSArray *subarray = [completeArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 5)];
NSArray *filteredArray = [subarray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate 
   predicateWithFormat:@"ANY (Other conditions here)"]
```

Comment: Thanks, simple and efficient!

Answer (score 0):

No, not really.  You could probably get something really hackish working by using a `SUBQUERY`, but even I, who am known to do unconventional things with predicates, think that would be a bad idea.

You say that you're doing this with CoreData.  If that's the case, then your request does not make sense, because CoreData does nothing with ordering things.  Yes you can specify sort descriptors to a fetch request, but those aren't applied until after the predicate is used.  Any data that gets processed by the predicate is inherently unordered.  So asking for an "array index value" to use in a predicate for CoreData would not only be an abuse of the predicate system, but represents an inherent misunderstanding about the CoreData framework.

CoreData is unordered.  Any ordering you want, you have to apply yourself.

Comment: Your comment is correct about core data not ordering contents. In my situation, the data is retrieved from core data and sorted with sort descriptors into an array. Later on further sorting is needed based on the position of objects with in the array and other conditions.

Comment: @Rob OK, then you're not really using CoreData at that point; by the time you want to reduce the set further, you have an array in memory.  That's a very important distinction.

Comment: Yeah true, but I just wanted to mention that the data could not be modified to store indexes or etc. Thanks for your assistance anyway.